# Bi-directional service not updating data in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm trying to get a bi-directional service working and can't figure out where I"m missing a step and or did something wrong.  There's no errors in the console, yet nothing happens when I attempt to send data through it.  ([Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/xJj2tWXeK5vkyiOjjZdB)) a plunker to what I have so far.

The process I'm trying to accomplish goes like this

Load this body of data into `app.ts` and iterate with `input.copmonent.ts`. *(done successfully)*.

```
{
  "questions":[
      {
        "question": "How tall are you?",
        "name": "height",
        "id": "heightCtrl",
        "template": "smInput"
      },
      {
        "question": "What is your favorite color?",
        "name": "color",
        "id": "colorCtrl",
        "template": "smInput"
      },
      {
        "question": "What kind of car do you drive?",
        "name": "car",
        "id": "carCtrl",
        "template": "smInput"
      }

    ]
}
```

Load data to new variable and use `ngModel` in template to update user response.  *(done successfully)*

```
//Input Component (omitted for relevance)

@Component({
    template:`
             <ng-container *ngIf="Qdata.template == 'smInput'">


                 <p>{{Qdata.question}}</p>

                 <input type="text"
                     id="Qdata.id"
                     name="Qdata.name"
                     [(ngModel)]="Response.response"
                 >


             </ng-container>
             `
})

export class InputComponent implements OnInit{    

    @Input() Qdata: any;        //from app.ts

    Response: FormResponse={};  // new variable

    ngOnInit(){ this.prepResponse(); }

    prepResponse(){
        let a = this.Qdata;
        let b = this.Response;

        b.question = a.question;
        b.id = a.id;
        b.name = a.name;
    }
}



//    Note: FormResponse is a custom class I made that's shaped the same as
//    the json data with the addition of a "response:string='';" field.
```

Create service to receive data from the `Response` variable in `input.component.ts` and make available for `app.ts` to subscribe to. *(done successfully.... I think... for the most part)*

```
//Imports Observable and Subject from proper places

@Injectable()

export class AnswerService {

  private FormList = new Subject<FormResponse[]>();  // so far I think this is contributing
                                                        to the problem somehow.

  addResponse(data:FormResponse){
    this.FormList.next(data);
  }

  getFormList(): Observable<FormResponse[]>{
    return this.FormList.asObservable();
  }

}
```

Create function in `Input.component.ts` to send data to `addResponse()` function in service. *(done successfully.... I think)*

```
import { AnswerService }  from './answer.service';

@Component({
    template:`
         <ng-container *ngIf="Qdata.template == 'smInput'">
             <!--previous HTML -->

             <button (click)="sendResponse()">send</button>
             <!-- plan to ultimately use OnChanges, using this to test -->

        </ng-container>
         `,
    providers: [AnswerService]
})

export class InputComponent implements OnInit{    

    @Input() Qdata: any;

    Response: FormResponse={};


    constructor( private _ans : AnswerService ) {}

    ngOnInit(){ ... }   prepResponse(){...}

    sendResponse(): void{
        let a = this.Response;
        let grp = new FormResponse({
            question:a.question,
            response:a.response,
            id:a.id,
            name:a.name
        });

        this._ans.addResponse(grp);
    }

}
```

Create subscription to `FormList` in `app.ts`. (done successfully)

```
//app.ts (omitted for relevance)

import { AnswerService } from './answer.service';

@Component({
    providers: [ AnswerService ]
})

export class App implements OnInit{

    FormData: Array<FormResponse>=[];

    constructor( private _ans : AnswerService ){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this._ans.getFormList().subscribe( list => { list = this.FormData; }); 
    }
}
```

After reaching this point everything loads up fine without any errors, but when I type something in the input fields and click send, nothing shows up in the binding I made in the `app.ts` template to show when a new object is added to the array.  When I try different methods, such as `push()` instead of `next()` I get errors telling me `this.FormList.push() is not a function`.  What do I need to do to get this to work?

I also want to point out that the reason I'm "copying data" in the `input.copmonent.ts` file is because in the real world usage of this the `Qdata` variable will have a lot more than just 4 properties, though it will only be sending those 4 to the `Response` variable to send back up to the parent component.

From this point forwards I plan to use the `FormData` variable to iterate a Template Driven Form with hidden pre-filled inputs something like this

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">

    <div *ngFor="let a of FormData">

        <div [attr.data-blank]="a.id" class="form-group">
        <!-- To force Angular to iterate a wrapper for each group -->

            <input type="hidden" class="form-control"
                [attr.name]="a.id" [(ngModel)]="a.question"
            >

            <input type="hidden" class="form-control"
                [attr.name]="a.name" [(ngModel)]="a.response"
            >
        </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

The reason I'm trying to do it this way is because the types of questionnaires I make have tons of optional questions nested within questions for multiple tiers [which you can see here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nBpriDOgC88Fo2WMpM6A?p=preview).  I'm hoping this will be a good way to collect the user's answers and put them all in one place without all the headaches.  As long as the `answer.service` is imported into the `input.component` it will always be able to send/update the list no matter what direction the user goes and what circumstance of inputs it requires.  What do I need to do to make sure the `answer.service` can deliver for this use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues here, the first issue is that your `child component` is also flagging the `answer service` as a provider, so it gets a new instance of  **AnswerService** instead of getting the same instance of the service as the parent.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'input-component',
  templateUrl: 'src/input.component.html'
  // No providers
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit{

  // ...

  /** Gets same instance of AnswerService as the parent component */
  constructor(private _ans: AnswerService){}

  sendResponse(): void{
    this._ans.addResponse(this.Response);
  }     
}
```

Also, the `getter` for your `FormList` was incorrect, I suggest using this approach as in the [official example](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service).

Your service should look like this.

```
@Injectable()
export class AnswerService {

      private _formList = new Subject<any>();
      public FormList = this._formList.asObservable();

      addResponse(event: FormResponse){
          this._formList.next(event);
      }
}
```

Now on your `app.component` you need to subscribe to the events like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl:'src/app.html',
  providers: [ QuestionService, AnswerService ]
})
export class App implements OnInit{

  FormData: FormResponse[] = [];

  // ...

  answerSubscription = this._ans.FormList.subscribe(a => {
    console.log('gets here '+JSON.stringify(a, null, '\t') )
    this.FormData.push(a)
  })

  // ...
}
```

Note that in the subscription I'm appending the result to the `FormData` Array.
The `QuestionService` code probably needs some touching up but you get the idea.

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qkiVP8UruRy0WNNnJDLY?p=preview) working!

Comment: YES THIS WORKS!.  Only thing is I don't understand why the data isn't passing with the object.

Comment: Fixed, the issue is in the `sendResponse` method, I'll update the answer . The plunker has a working fix.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it.  Now on to understanding why this works lol.

Comment: No problem! happy to help